# What DBMS is used by ArcGIS Online?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-online, database

I work in an Oracle shop. My I.T. department uses [ArcGIS Online](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/what-is-agol.htm) to host data for use in data collection activities.

The data goes through a yearly cycle:

1. Export from our Oracle enterprise geodatabase
2. Import to ArcGIS Online
3. Edit on tablets or phones via the [Collector](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/overview/overview.htm) app during the course of the year
4. Export to a file geodatabase
5. Process the data
6. Import back into the Oracle enterprise geodatabase

I'm involved in steps 1, 5, and 6. But, it has occurred to me that I have no idea what goes on in step 2. Out of curiosity, what is the underlying DBMS of ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Unless someone from Esri flags this and wants to provide an official answer, it would seem to me that anyone else saying what DBMS(s) are used by them for ArcGIS Online can only be speculative.  My understanding is that Esri tries to treat all its DBMS options as being equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is this, ArcGIS online is a "blackBox". Esri won't release the exact details to the public. I understand the desire to know but some companies prefer to keep info like this away from the public domain.